# Android Studio do not sees a Chrome device

Tags: linux, android-studio, flutter, flutter-web

I am using a Flutter SDK for building a web application.
In these latter days i am trying to working on Linux, and i ran into a problem: Android Studio do not sees a Chrome in device list.
You can say what Flutter SDK is not properly configured, but no - Flutter seed a chrome device, and also Flutter can run a application in chrome via `flutter run -d chrome` command.

Has anyone encountered a same problem?

Flutter doctor output:

```
[urusai@mikhail-pc ka4alka-voting]$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.14.6, on Linux, locale ru_RU.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.14.6 at /usr/lib/flutter
    • Framework revision fabeb2a16f (4 недели назад), 2020-01-28 07:56:51 -0800
    • Engine revision c4229bfbba
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.5.0 fc3af737c7)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/urusai/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • CHROME_EXECUTABLE = /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 80.0.3987.122
    • Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools

• No issues found!
```

[image: Android Studio]

Comment: Try to invalidate the cache and restart android studio. You can see the option under `File -> invalidate cache and restart`

Comment: Of course i tried

Answer (score 0):

Try launch Android studio via terminal.

if it the case, that Chrome(web) device is shown only when u run it via terminal. This means if u can copy your bash `~/.bashrc` environment variable to user wide variable `~/.profile` it can be fixed.

Try set up your environment variable in ~/.profile so it the same in ~/.bashrc